# Mixed mode content - How do I select text from h1 but don't include its child element's text?

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, css-selectors

I have trouble printing simple text from a `<h1>` element:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<h1><em>Name</em>A Johnson </h1>")
puts doc.at_xpath("//h1").content
```

It outputs:

```
NameA Johnson
```

I want just `A Johnson` in the output. Is it possible to select just this text using XPath or CSS selectors?

Comment: Selecting just text nodes with XPath as suggested is the best.  Could also using the hack:  `doc.at('h1').children.last.text`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using `text()` XPath function? Like this (untested though):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<h1><em>Name</em>A Johnson </h1>")
puts doc.at_xpath("//h1/text()").content
```

Answer (score 1):

These solutions may only give part of the story. Consider:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML("<h1><em>Name</em>A <br>Johnson </h1>")
puts doc.at_xpath("//h1/text()").content

=> A

puts doc.at('h1').children.last.text

=> Johnson
```

or my suggestion:

```
puts doc.search("h1/text()").text

=> A Johnson
```