# storing the attribute value from the node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following XML

```
<div class="new_select">
  <select id="Schwarzkopf Live Hair Colour1" class="sf_input" name="id[8]">
       <option value="0">Select Schwarzkopf Live Hair Colour</option>
       <option disabled="" value="199">Black #1.0 </option>
</select>
</div>
```

And I want to save the attribute value id (Schwarzkopf Live Hair Colour1) for the the node 'select'

Can't remember the function for this. Help Please.

Answer (score 0):

If this were your entire XML file, then you could use this:

```
/div/select/@id
```

to access the `id` attribute of that select.  If it's not, this would find that attribute:

```
//select/@id
```

but it would also find `id` attributes on all the other `select`s if there are any others.  Is there a chance that there will be more than one `select`?  Is there a way to uniquely single out this one?

Comment: You guessed rightly, it is not the only select. But I can uniquely identify this select.  I am using ruby/capybara and trying to store this id.   dropdown = browser.find(:xpath, "//div[@id='addtocart_modal']//select/@id").  But it is not working. I am getting this error message  "The given selector //div[@id='addtocart_modal']//select/@id is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
InvalidSelectorError: The result of the xpath expression "//div[@id='addtocart_modal']//select/@id" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.

Comment: The error suggests that you can only use find() to select an element, and not an attribute. From the comments on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437585/select-mixed-mode-content-in-capybara), it sounds like this is a limitation in the XPath support of a certain driver Capybara uses.  The suggested workaround there is to use the selenium-webdriver or Nokogiri.